# Webpack'ing "sass" (dart-sass), uses require dynamically, hard code dependencies into context?

Tags: webpack

### Problem

The "sass" bundle contains a module, sass.dart.js: https://runpkg.com/?sass@1.21.0/sass.dart.js

Amongst other things, this contains dynamic usage of `require` (many lines redacted):

```
var self = Object.create(global);
self.require = require;

//...

u($,"N0","Hq",function(){return self.require("readline")})
u($,"Mr","cN",function(){return self.require("fs")})
u($,"MN","Ho",function(){return self.require("chokidar")})
```

This use of require prevents static analysis by webpack, resulting in the error in the output (also in this gist) and a webpackEmptyContext being created in the bundle. This naturally doesn't work :)

### Options Tried

I've seen the `ContextReplacementPlugin`, I don't think this applies here as the usage is not a direct require call.

I've seen `noParse`, but that feels like the nuclear approach, and I don't know what the potential negative side effects may be.

### Reproduction code

Also in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/tchetwin/eeeffdfbbf973b59f05a3ecba3ab253a)

index.js:

```
const sass = require("sass");
console.log(sass);
```

webpack.config.js:

```
module.exports = (env) => ({
    entry: "./index.js",
    mode: "development",
    target: "node"
});
```

package.json:

```
{
  "devDependencies": {
    "webpack": "^4.34.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.4"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "sass": "^1.21.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build": "webpack-cli"
  }
}
```

### Goal

How can I configure the context for this particular module to specifically list `readline`/`fs`/`chokidar` as dependencies, possibly to produce some context that only provides those values?

I don't mind if the solution is a little brittle and would require pinning of the version of dart-sass.

Comment: Why do you need to `require("sass")`?

Comment: The `index.js` file doesn't give a lot away, I admit! We're using sass programmatically in the node build tool we maintain. We bundle this tool for ease/speed of distribution, hence trying to webpack sass.

This index.js file doesn't not actually trigger the error when run, for that I'd have to expand the repro case to include some sass files, but it's getting quite library specific then.

Answer (score 0):

We've arrived at a "solution" that implements a custom, dart-sass specific loader to prepend code to the module to bypass the static analysis.

sass-prepend-loader.js:

```
const SASS_PREPEND_CODE = `require = (function () {
  var fs = require("fs");
  var readline = require("readline");
  return function (mod) {
    switch (mod) {
      case "fs": return fs;
      case "readline": return readline;
      default: throw new Error("Unexpected sass dependency");
    }
  };
})();`

module.exports = function(source) {
    this.cacheable();
    this.callback(null, `${SASS_PREPEND_CODE}\n${source}`);
};
```

webpack.config.js (excerpt):

```
module: {
    rules: [
        {
            resource: path.resolve(__dirname, "node_modules", "sass", "sass.dart.js"),
            loader: path.resolve(__dirname, "sass-prepend-loader.js"),
        }
    ],
},
```

This is tailored specifically to the current "sass" version, 1.20.3, and possibly also behaviour in current webpack. Note: we're not passing through the "chokidar" dependency, our use case does not require it.

It works by assigning to `require` with a version that can only serve up "fs" and "readline". Webpack replaces the `replace` called with `__webpack_require__` calls (satisfying its desire to statically analyse) and allows `require` (now shadowed) to stick around.

Extract from dist/index.js:

```
/***/ (function(module, exports, __webpack_require__) {

(function(module, exports, __webpack_require__) {

eval("/* WEBPACK VAR INJECTION */(function(__filename) {var require;require = (function () {\n  var fs = __webpack_require__(/*! fs */ \"fs\");\n  var readline = __webpack_require__(/*! readline */ \"readline\");\n  return function (mod) {\n    switch (mod) {\n      case \"fs\": return fs;\n      case \"readline\": return readline;\n      default: throw new Error(\"Unexpected sass dependency\");\n    }\n  };\n})();\n// make sure to keep this as 'var'\n// we don't want block scoping\nvar self = Object.create(global);\n\nself.scheduleImmediate = self.setImmediate\n    ? function (cb) {\n        global.setImmediate(cb);\n      }\n    : function(cb) {\n        setTimeout(cb, 0);\n      };\n\nself.require = require;

//...

self.require(\"fs\")
```

---

Hope that this is a temporary solution and that we can arrive at a better solution from one of these avenues:

- [dart-sass Issue](https://github.com/sass/dart-sass/issues/726)
- [ContextReplacementPlugin](https://twitter.com/wSokra/status/1141050157733203968)